# How do I use jQuery to filter a table?

Tags: jquery, html-table, coffeescript, filtering

I'm stuck trying to implement a user-configurable filter on a table using jQuery (in coffeescript).

I have annotated each row in my table with a CSS class that identifies its category and brand:

```
<table id="items_list">
  <tr>
    <th>Foo</th> 
    ... <!-- 6 header columns -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="category-12 brand-37">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="category-17 brand-4">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
```

I have `<select>` dropdown listing all of the categories, so I tried to hook on to it's onChange event to filter out only the rows in the table that match that category's ID. Here's what I've got so far -- it executes every time I change the category, but the selected_records is always null.

```
jQuery -> 
  items = $("#items-list").html()  # works - though it has a <tbody> around it
  $('#category_id').change ->      # gets the onChange for the category dropdown
    category_id = $('#category_id :selected').val() # this works, I get the id
    # this next line always returns null
    selected_records = $(items).filter("tr[class=category-#{category_id}]").html()
    $('#items_list').html(selected_records)
```

That second last line must be wrong, but I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to get the `html` and manipulate with it. You can basically just show/hide the `tr` elements inside the `table`. Also you can just use `this.val()` to get the selected value of a `select` element inside the `change` event handler. Try this.

```
  var items = $("#items-list tr")
  $('#category_id').change(function(){
      //First hide all the trs
      //then filter trs based on category-id class and show them
      items.hide().filter(".category-" + $(this).val()).show();
  });
```

Comment: Beauty - thanks. I just realised this strategy throws away my <th> row, but I think I can fix that. Thanks for your help!